# Cannot find adb under platform-tools

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools, android-tools-namespace

I have installed android-sdk through command line

command - `brew install --cask android-sdk`

and have also installed the platform tools. I have this folder structure

`/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

under this, i have the following:

emulator
licenses
patcher
platform-tools
platforms
system-images
tools

there is no adb inside platform tools, in fact it is empty. I do have adb installed which is under: `/usr/local/bin/adb`

Now , when I build - I keep getting the error :

```
 An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 
Could not find 'adb' in ["/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/adb",
"/usr/local/share/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb","/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/adb",
"/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/bin/adb",
"/usr/local/share/android-sdk/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/usr/local/share/android-sdk'?
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `brew install --cask android-platform-tools`